# Android foreground service lose context

Tags: java, android, service, multitasking, foreground

I have a little problem understanding what's going on with a service lifecycle that I created. 
My Application declare and use a service "LocalisationSevice" which its goal is to start a location listener and add the updated location to an array.

Simple as that. The service run foreground.

The problem is that if I manually kill my application though the task switcher or eclipse the service will stay (GPS and notification are here in the notification area). Thats fine, it is what I want, if I click on the notification it will take me back to my application saved state. 
But now
 the problem is if I launch the application by clicking on the icon instead of the service notification it will start the application from the start. But it should restore the application into the latest state no ? Like if I have clicked on the service notification.

I start the service like this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, LocalisationService.class);
startService(i);
```

Here is the code of the service:

```
public class LocalisationService extends Service {

private LocationManager locationManager;
private LocationListener locationListener;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.iconsmall,
            "Notification text", System.currentTimeMillis());
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
    Intent i = new Intent(this, RouteActivity.class);

    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, i, 0);

    notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, "Notification title",
            "notification message)", pi);
    startForeground(1337, notification);
    startListenLocation();
    return (START_NOT_STICKY);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    stopListenLocation();
    stopForeground(true);
}

public void startListenLocation() {
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            CurrentRouteManager.getSharedManager().updateWithLocation(
                    location);
        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,
                Bundle extras) {

        }

        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

        }

    };
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0,
            200, locationListener);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 200, locationListener);
}

public void stopListenLocation() {
        locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
}
```

If I kill the application and then relaunch it by the service it will call onStartCommand(); again.
Also it seems that I lost the link with the location listener, when i'll destroy the service after relaunching it, the notification icon disapear but not the GPS icon.

Edit: Here is the interesting part of my Manifest file
The part about the actvity from where the service is started

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.wayzup.activity.RouteActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:launchMode="singleTop" >
    </activity>
```

And the part about my service

```
  <service android:name="com.wayzup.services.LocalisationService" >
        </service>
```

Comment: start it as START_STICKY

Comment: I changed to return (START_STICKY); But still, if I kill the app, and launch it by the normal icon (not the service notification) it will start from the beginning.

Comment: i think clear_top and single_top should be declared in your manifest, not in the intent in the notification. that can explain the different behaviours

Comment: I set android:launchMode="singleTop" in the manifest for the activity used in the pending Intent. Still the same problem :/

Comment: look in the logcat for the starting activity line (logged by ActivityManager i think). you'll have the flags used, a few details on the intent, as well, and you may be able to compare and see what defers.

Comment: What is the normal behavior if I have a service running and that I manually kill the application ?

Comment: Any idea ? THe big inconsistency is that a touch on the notification or on the application icon does not launch the application the same way...