# Application lose current activity after 1 hour

Tags: java, android, service, android-activity, multitasking

My application is quite simple, I have a few activities (a `LoginActivity` which is the launcher and the main activity). Then I have some other activities and finally an activity `RouteActivity` which launches a service.

The `LocationService` extends `Service` and `startForeground` with a notification. The service just starts a `LocationListener` and register every new GPS location point. 
The service appears to work just fine, if I touch the notification icon it bring me back to my application activity from where it was started (not from the Login activity).

Now here is the problem, if I touch the application icon (on the Android launcher) it sometimes lauch my app to the right and current activty `RouteActivity`, but after around 1 hour, if I touch the application icon it just restart the application from the beginning and start the `LoginActivity`.

But if I touch my service notification if bring me back to the right and background activity. 
Also my service is not killed, never, so it seems to work just fine, objects and variable tied to the application are still there.

So what ? I have 2 instances of my application running ? I'm kinda lost on this one, especially that it seems to be time related.

This "bug" is produced on Android 2.X, I can't reproduce it on Android 4.X. It is kinda hard to debug because I have to let the application run for around 1 hour. And after that time I have no special message in logcat.

I noted something: 
The ActivityManager messages are quite strange, if I launch my application through the service notification in the notification center it log:

`Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x14000000 cmp=com.wayzup.wayzupapp/com.wayzup.activity.RouteActivity bnds=[0,149][320,213]`

While if I launch it trough the application icon it's logged, but the actual activity shown is not the login one but the actual RouteActivity which actually launched the service. (After around 1 hour it is effectively the `LoginActivity` which is started).

```
 Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.wayzup.wayzupapp/com.wayzup.activity.LoginActivity bnds=[3,338][77,417]
```

Each time I launch the RouteActivity I also have this log

```
Activity idle timeout for HistoryRecord{44e78808 com.wayzup.wayzupapp/com.wayzup.activity.RouteActivity}
```

This is related to my other question: [Android foreground service lose context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12564620/android-foreground-service-lose-context)
But I think this one is the real problem and more accurate.

I can post some code if you want to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally resolved my problem. 
Now it does not matter if the activity is killed or not, as long as the service is alive it's fine.
In my `LoginActivity` I check for if my service, if it's running I start the `RouteActivity` which is bound to it and `singleTop`. Si I always have the single and same instance of it.

```
@Override
public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        if (checkMyServiceRunningOrNot()){
            restoreAcitivty();
        }
    }

public void restoreAcitivty(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, RouteActivity.class); 
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intent); 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're relying on an activity task stack to maintain all your state. I suggest you use instead use something like [PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences()](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/preference/PreferenceManager.html#getDefaultSharedPreferences%28android.content.Context) to maintain the logged in / logged out state. That way your can survive if its activities are terminated and recreated.

The way I tend to do it is have your main activity be the one you want the user to see once they're logged in. In its `onCreate()` check to see if the user is logged in and if not, `startActivityForResult()` to send them off to the login activity. Persist the logged in state somewhere so that you can check it in the main activity's `onCreate()`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response, I actually use sharedPref to store login state. The application can log you automatically. But the activity I need to maintain is not the first, second or third screen. It's a very specific one. Actually the app can restore its state on its own but it's not very intuitive for the user. Maybe I can check for a running service on my login activity ?

Comment: Just to clarify: your service is still running fine, but your activities are getting killed, yes? And yes, whatever activity needs to talk with the service should just bind to it to see if it's still running. If your service runs in the same process as your Activity, you can use the LocalBinder pattern. Otherwise you'll have to start digging into aidl in order to do bi-directional communication.

Comment: So I should bind my service to the activity ? Then the activity will have the same priority than the service and should only be killed in extreme cases ? Or will it make my service to be killed faster. As i understand the binding, if my app/activity is killed the service will be killed with it. Sound less persistent than my current setup, true? I'll try anyway.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still unclear about your situation. Is the service being killed?

Comment: Ok, so if the service is staying alive, that's good! An activity binding to a service is only a temporary thing. You can unbind and the service will stay running (assuming you returned the right flag in `onStartCommand()`). I'm not sure why you care so much about your activity staying alive in the background. Generally speaking, you should just design your app with notion that all your activities will be killed when you aren't using them.